# Cambio de Idioma en Visual Studio 2019 (IDE)

Tags: visual-studio-2019, idioma

Tengo una duda como puedo cambiar de idioma al Español despues de instalar Visual Studio, me olvide de seleccionar el Idioma español y queria saber si se puede cambiar despues de Instalarlo...

---

ya pude instalar el paquete en Español

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Abre el visual studio installer, selecciona modificar> paquetes de idioma, e instala el paquete de idioma que prefieras.

Answer (score 1):

Si está en inglés:

```
Tools -> Options -> International Settings -> [Idioma]
```

Si no está en esa lista necesitarás instalarlo:

```
Tools -> Get tools and features -> Languages
```